# Exposing Database Operations as Webservice

Tags: web-services, spring, hibernate, web-applications, architecture

Scenario:

In my project, we have a web service (Apache CXF, Hibernate and Spring) to expose some services to third party, Portal (Spring MVC, Portal and Hibernate) for developing the front end web application and some Batch (Spring Batch, Hibernate) operations running separately.

All 3 applications using the same Database and having the mapping & entity managers at application level.

Problem:

The above scenario creates problem of updating the same mapping almost in 3 places and we couldn't able to enable caching also due to the same entity will be updated in multiple applications and each having the separate entity managers.

My Solution:

I have planned to introduce one web service which will take care of all the Database operations and will be used by the other 3 applications. So it will avoid the above problem.

Could you please help me to fine tune my solution or help to get the new best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ganesh, centralising your updates to the database in one place as you describe will help you in this situation.  What you haven't described is how you expose the web service and where the real work of understanding table relationships happens.

The real advantage you can gain by making your changes is in centralising the business logic about the table updates in that same web service (or possibly somewhere else). The web service could then expose business objects.

A typical simplified example:

```
    Business Purchase Order = Table Purchase Order
                            + Table Purchase Order Lines
                            + Stock Available reduced by Order Quantity
```

The last thing I would want is for multiple applications to have to manage those table updates, or have to call the Stock application in a tightly-bound relationship to reduce Stock Available.  However, exposing a Business Purchase Order and worrying about the related table updates in your new web service would make sure it happened the same way every time increasing your system's maintainability.

If you think about the web service exposure as a combination of objects, as below, then you might consider whether you want to rethink what the web service is really doing and whether you want another layer of abstraction, but that's a longer discussion.

```
                    WEB SERVICE
               +-------------------+
               | Service Contract  |
               +---------+---------+
    Message -> | Message | Core    |
               + Parsing | Service | <-> Backend <-> Persistent Storage
    Message <- + Logic   | Logic   |     + other 
               +---------+---------+     Services
```

I hope I haven't just stated the obvious and that this helps. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @geoffc.. I have had exactly the some thoughts, But you gave me an excellent picture to think in all areas... Working with team on the discussion on this change now. Thanks for your help.